# Type Error of new: differents __new__ and _new_

Tags: python

What is the difference between `__new__` (double underscore) and `_new_` (single underscore)? I can't understand it.

Look at the following code. It uses the double underscore `__new__` function and doesn't work:

```
class B(object):
    def __new__(cls,*a,**b):
        ne = object.__new__(cls,*a,**b)
        setattr(ne,"created at",datetime.datetime.now())
        return ne
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        print("initteyiz")
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

h=B(1,2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
h=B(1,2)
File "<pyshell#29>", line 3, in __new__
ne = object.__new__(cls,*a,**b)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

But it works with a single underscore `_new_`:

```
class B(object):
    def _new_(cls,*a,**b):
        ne = object._new_(cls,*a,**b)
        setattr(ne,"created at",datetime.datetime.now())
        return ne
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        print("initteyiz")
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

e=B(1,2)
initteyiz
print(e)
<__main__.B object at 0x000000000337A518>
```

Why does this work?

Comment: In your 2nd example you are not defining a `__new__` magic method, you are simply defining a method called `_new_`. The object is then made as per normal with the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3):

`__new__` is a [Python special method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) used to control the creation of an instance of a particular class.  It is invoked before `__init__`, which is a special method used to control the *initialization* of that instance.

`_new_` is just a normal method.  The underscores mean nothing, expect maybe that the method is meant to be private.  [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) states that a single underscore placed before a method name means that the method is meant to be used as if it were private (there are no truly private methods in Python).

---

With the above points in mind, the error generated by the first example can be explained as follows:

1. When this line is run:

   ```
   e=B(1,2)
   ```

   `B.__new__` is invoked implicitly and given the positional arguments `1` and `2`.
2. This line inside `B.__new__` is then executed:

   ```
   ne = object.__new__(cls,*a,**b)
   ```

   Moreover, it tries to pass on to `object.__new__` the arguments given to `B.__new__`.
3. `object.__new__` does not accept any arguments aside from `cls`, which is a reference to class `B` itself.  Therefore, a `TypeError` is thrown.

The second example does not throw an error because, as stated above, `_new_` is just a normal method.  Hence, it is not invoked implicitly when you instantiate class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are using the special type constructor method `__new__`, but are calling the base type’s `__new__` incorrectly. The base type is `object`, and the type constructor for `object` itself does not take any parameters. But you pass the parameters `1` and `2` onto `object.__new__`.

If you don’t pass those parameters, it works just fine:

```
class B(object):
    def __new__(cls,*a,**b):
        ne = object.__new__(cls) # <- here
        setattr(ne,"created at",datetime.datetime.now())
        return ne
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        print("initteyiz")
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

In your second example, you are using `_new_`, which is just a normal method, so nothing fancy happens. And of course it isn’t called on object construction.